# Bootstrap navbar with class "navbar-fixed-top" not staying fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my website, I am using the navbar-fixed-top class as per bootstrap's docs.  I want my nav to stay fixed but unfortunately the position becomes relative upon viewing the page source.  Here is my code.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navId">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ url_for('home')}}" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('notebook_reference')}}" class="nav-link active">Work</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am quite confused on this.  I believe I have followed [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-fixed-top) properly.  If someone knows my error here, let me know!

One more thing.  I have NOT overriden any styles of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar fixed-top">
```

Just remove "-" between navbar and fixed top